# SQL: CASE WHEN not working

Tags: sql, case-when

I am trying to return either "Increased adjustment" or "Decreased adjustment" depending on the value in the "amount" column being positive or negative.

```
CASE amount
when amount > 0 then "Increase Adjustment"
when amount < 0 then "Decreased Adjustment"
else "ERROR"
end as 
transaction_type
```

Any advise would be greatly appreciated...

Edit: Entire select=:

```
select
tx_date,
bank_account,
description,
amount,
currency,
CASE bank_account
when 'CAD-FTX' then 'Suspense_CAD'
when 'USD-PRO' then 'Suspense_USD'
when 'CAD-PRO' then 'Suspense_CAD'
when 'USD-ALL' then 'Suspense_USD'
when 'TD-USA' then 'Suspense_USD'
end
suspense_account,
CASE amount
when cast(amount as float) > 0 then "Increase Adjustment"
when cast(amount as float) < 0 then "Decreased Adjustment"
end 
transaction_type
from [sys_tx_combined]
```

Comment: Your sign is the same, change the applicable one to < and rerun

Comment: Also don't forget the 'D' at the end of the word 'Increase'

Answer (score 1):

```
select tx_date, bank_account, description, amount, currency, 
CASE 
    when bank_account ='CAD-FTX' then 'Suspense_CAD' 
    when bank_account = 'USD-PRO' then 'Suspense_USD' 
    when bank_account = 'CAD-PRO' then 'Suspense_CAD' 
    when bank_account = 'USD-ALL' then 'Suspense_USD' 
    when bank_account = 'TD-USA' then 'Suspense_USD' 
end suspense_account, 
CASE 
    when cast(amount as float) > 0 then 'Increase Adjustment' 
    when cast(amount as float) < 0 then 'Decreased Adjustment' 
end 
transaction_type 
from [sys_tx_combined]
```

Comment: Still the same error... Thank you for the response though.

Comment: Can you post the entire select statement please?

Comment: `select
    tx_date,
    bank_account,
    description,
    amount,
    currency,
    CASE bank_account
    when 'CAD-FTX' then 'Suspense_CAD'
    when 'USD-PRO' then 'Suspense_USD'
    when 'CAD-PRO' then 'Suspense_CAD'
    when 'USD-ALL' then 'Suspense_USD'
    when 'TD-USA' then 'Suspense_USD'
   end
   suspense_account,
   CASE amount
   when cast(amount as float) > 0 then "Increase Adjustment"
   when cast(amount as float) < 0 then "Decreased Adjustment"
   end 
   transaction_type
   from [sys_tx_combined]`

Comment: One thing, change the double quotes to single quotes surrounding the increase and decrease adjustment

Comment: Try updated code above - also what kind of field is 'amount'?

Comment: 'd' from Increase adjustment needs to be added too

Comment: Amount is numeric, 2 decimal places and ranges from positive to negative.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
CASE
when amount > 0 then "Increase Adjustment"
when amount < 0 then "Decreased Adjustment"
else "ERROR"
end as 
transaction_type
```

Comment: Damn didn't even notice, thanks for pointing that out but I'm still getting the same error. "operator does not exist: numeric = boolean"

Comment: Please add a whole SQL statement. Maybe the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Just added it sorry about that. "operator does not exist: numeric = boolean"

Answer (score 0):

Because you start your statement with

```
CASE amount
```

You're specifying a simple CASE expression over amount, meaning the WHEN clauses can only be equality checks. Try a searched expression:

```
CASE
when amount > 0 then "Increase Adjustment"
when amount < 0 then "Decreased Adjustment"
else "ERROR"
end as 
transaction_type
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thank you for the response! The same sign was just a typo, i fixed it for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE
when amount > '0' then "Increased Adjustment"
when amount < '0' then "Decreased Adjustment"
else "ERROR"
end as 
transaction_type
```

Comment: Don't think the `amount` column is varchar.

Comment: Is there a way to make it varchar in the query?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler way to write your expressions:

```
select tx_date, bank_account, description, amount, currency,
       (case when bank_account in ('CAD-FTX', 'CAD-PRO')
             then 'Suspense_CAD'
             when bank_account in ('USD-PRO', 'USD-ALL', 'TD-USA')
             then 'Suspense_USD'
         end) suspense_account,
       (case when amount > 0 then 'Increase Adjustment'
             when amount < 0 then 'Decreased Adjustment'
        end) as transaction_type
from [sys_tx_combined];
```

Notes:

- When working with `case` expressions for such mapping, I prefer to have one condition for each output condition, rather than one condition for each input.
- The `cast(amount as float)` almost certainly is not necessary, so I removed it.
- Use singe quotes for string constants, even if your database supports double quotes (those should be used for other purposes).

Comment: Thank you for the response! Really appreciate the help. Amount is an numeric value, 2 decimal places and negative & positive values. Thank you again for the response!

Comment: Why would you cast it to a `float` for a comparison?

Comment: Was just following someone's advice from a different comment. I don't know how to change the value to make it work